# How to pass an object as parameter to an onClick function using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

I have an object that I need to pass to a function, this function is trigger via `onClick` and `onKeyUp()`, but I couldn't make it work.
Although I can pass values to it.

```
function myFunc(myObj) {

 $("<button type="button" onclick='otherFunction( $(\"#elem\").val() )'
onkeyup='otherFunction( $(\"#elem\").val() )'> CLICK IT </button>"
}
```

As you can see, i have a `otherFunction` and I Can pass the `$("#elem").val()` as a parameter. But I need to also pass `myObj` to it.
Tried everything I could think of and I was unable to make it work.

*Obs: `myObj` is a marker from googleMaps, so I can't just pass it's attributes values. I need to access the full object on my second function. 
   Because I need to do something like: `myObj.setOptions(.....)`*

Comment: I think your script is not proper so if you write it clearly then i can help you.

Comment: @pankaj98 Not sure how to do that. It's a javascript function that uses jquery to create a button with `onclick` and `onkeyup` in it. And I'm having difficult passing the parameter because it's an object and not just a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using jQuery to create button, use `.on()` to bind event handler's. The object `myObj` will be accessible in the event handler due to [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```
function myFunc(myObj) {
    var button = $('<button>', {
            "type": "button",
            "text": "CLICK IT"
        }).on('click keyup', function () {
            // myObj will be accessible here
            otherFunction($("#elem").val());
        });
}
```

A good read [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: may I normally pass the `myObj` to the function ? Like: `otherFunction($("#elem").val(), myObj);`

Comment: Amazing ! I'm just having some trouble to append it to another object using `appendTo()`. Is it possible to do something like `button.appendTo($('myDiv'));` ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro, Yes mate, provided you have an `myDiv` element

Answer (score 1):

this code explained how you send data to the handler with jQuery

```
$('yourElement').click(yourData, function(eventObject){
    var thisIsYourData = eventObject.data;
})
```